# Javascript effect - wind

Tags: javascript, effect

I have a background of nature on a website. I have a div in the middle pages. I would like to use `javascript:` in order to object rippled (from side to side).

Can I do the effect of wind? - The object div.

Comment: This is extremely broad, and it has attracted a link-only answer. I think this should be put on hold for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many JavaScript Animation Frameworks that could help you easily accomplish this.  One example being [Glimmer](http://visitmix.com/work/glimmer/) that you could check out.